# echo http server tornado

Tags: python, http, echo, tornado

How can I create an HTTP echo server from Tornado?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import signal
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.tcpserver import TCPServer
import tornado.web

def handle_signal(sig, frame):
    IOLoop.instance().add_callback(IOLoop.instance().stop)

class EchoServer(TCPServer):
    def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
        self._stream = stream
        self._read_line()

    def _read_line(self):
        self._stream.read_until('\n' ,self._handle_read)

    def _handle_read(self, data):
        self._stream.write(data, '\n')
        self._read_line()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_signal)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_signal)
    server = EchoServer()
    server.bind(8001)
    server.start(25)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
    IOLoop.instance().close()
```

How do I make of this http echo server 
what's wrong? not much i am newbie
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your question would be more clear if you explained what happened when you run this code, and what you expected instead.
2. One TCPServer object may handle many connections, so instead of assigning to self.stream in `handle_stream`, you should make a new object to handle this stream.
3. The second argument to stream.write is a callback; it looks like you meant `self._stream.write(data + '\n')`.

Comment: when I run this code, run TCP echo server , he says to me as it should only telnet and I have answered me that he also http, there is a question about http echo server in node.js but I need to TORNADO

Comment: in general, it is necessary that the server accepts POST request (body POST request is json)

Comment: If you want HTTP, you should start with an HTTPServer, not a plain TCPServer.